# AS 3 Importing a class file from timeline Instead Document Properites

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I need some help please.

I have a class file and i have importing it as you can see from the image below:

[image]

And the code of this file is:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import fl.motion.AdjustColor;
    import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;
    import fl.events.SliderEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var color:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
        private var filter:ColorMatrixFilter;

        public function Main():void
        {
            /* Required to create initial Matrix */

            color.brightness = 0;
            color.contrast = 0;
            color.hue = 0;
            color.saturation = 0;

            /* Add Listeners function */

            addListeners();

        }

        private final function addListeners():void
        {
            colorPanel.brightSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustBrightness);
            colorPanel.contSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustContrast);
            colorPanel.hueSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustHue);
            colorPanel.satSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustSaturation);
        }

        private final function adjustBrightness(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.brightness = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private final function adjustContrast(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.contrast = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private final function adjustHue(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.hue = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private final function adjustSaturation(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.saturation = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private final function update():void
        {
            filter = new ColorMatrixFilter(color.CalculateFinalFlatArray());
            image.filters = [filter];
        }






    }
}
```

Now i want to import this file from timeline. Is it possible;
I i remove the class name from the document properties and import it from timeline (frame1) like: import Main

Nothing happens.

Thanks!

Comment: ok so you imported it. Are you making an instance of it? For example: `var main:Main = new Main();`

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to what I believe you are doing would be something like this..

Here is an example: http://dopserv1.dop.com/ColorMatrixExample.swf

Now to explain; in your FLA:

```
import Main;

var main:Main = new Main();
addChild(main);
```

And you Main.as class will be:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import fl.motion.AdjustColor;
    import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;
    import fl.events.SliderEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var color:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
        private var filter:ColorMatrixFilter;
        private var panel:ColorPanel;
        private var image:Image;

        public function Main():void
        {
            /* Required to create initial Matrix */
            color.brightness = 0;
            color.contrast = 0;
            color.hue = 0;
            color.saturation = 0;
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            panel = new ColorPanel();
            panel.x = 15;
            panel.y = 15;
            addChild(panel);

            image = new Image();
            image.x = 150;
            image.y = 150;
            addChild(image);

            panel.brightSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, adjustBrightness);
            panel.contSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, adjustContrast);
            panel.hueSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, adjustHue);
            panel.satSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, adjustSaturation);
        }

        private function adjustBrightness(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.brightness = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private function adjustContrast(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.contrast = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private function adjustHue(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.hue = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private function adjustSaturation(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.saturation = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private function update():void
        {
            filter = new ColorMatrixFilter(color.CalculateFinalFlatArray());
            image.filters = [filter];
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my Library of the FLA, I simply imported an image, made a movie clip out of it and gave it a linkage name of `Image`. Delete it from the stage once its created.

Then for your `colorPanel`, I drug 4 sliders to the stage, named them according to the names in your class and created one movie clip out of them with an instance name of `ColorPanel`. Delete it from the stage once its created.

Also note: I changed your SliderEvent.CHANGE to SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG as I would expect this is more of the result you are looking for.

Comment: Dear Ronnie, Thanks for your instant answer. Is it possible to have your email? I want to ask you something!

Comment: Thanks Ronnie, Great Job!! You saved my life!